# munin - critical item mailqueue

Tags: debian, email

I have just installed a new Debian Jessie server..

In munin monitoring there is 1 critical item: `Mailqueue`

What is that? Haven't installed any mail service/server

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail functionality in the form of `/bin/mailx`, `/usr/lib/sendmail` and `/usr/sbin/sendmail` (whether actually provided by the classical sendmail MTA or a more lightweight replacement such exim) is a core part of a Linux system and part of the [Linux Standards Base](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/command.html#CMDUTIL) and the [POSIX requirements](http://www.unix.org/version4/) and should be present in any standards compliant Linux distribution.

So even if you didn't explicitly select a MTA one will be provided, as far as I know Debian and Ubuntu default to Exim.

Typically you'll find a sane default configuration that limits the mail functionality to only within the system.

Now for the messages in your queue: there are benign causes such as that messages are the result of a cron job that generates output, or they might be the result of abuse. You'll need to examine that queue to determine that.

`exim -bp`  will give you a listing of the messages in the queue and the Exim manual has a number of other [useful utilities](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-4.50/doc/html/spec_49.html) to easily collect more information.

Comment: Is there a fast way to check where the messages has their origin?

Comment: And is there a way to disable these mails when a cron job has an output. I have recently migrated from Debian whezzy to Debian jessie. Before there was not queried any mails.

Comment: Take a look at that queue first. Check your mailog. At the moment I know less than you do, you'll need to investigate first. That allows to check if there's abuse, a misconfiguration or something else...